# DateTime Format not recognized in input for Date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, date, razor, localization

It's been almost 4 hours googling this. I have a ViewModel with a DateTime property, which I don't need time:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Start Date is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Start date is not a valid date.")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

}
```

Then in my **edit view** I created an input using this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

I try to edit some entity which has a stardate value of **13/01/2016** (January 13th, 2016). My input is rendered as follow:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field StartDate must be a date." data-val-required="Start Date is required" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" type="date" value="13/01/2016" />
```

The datetimepicker looks like this, it doesn't show the date, it shows a **format placeholder** instead:

[image: Input Component]

Here in Brazil, the local format is dd/MM/yyyy (like in the input's value), so date is being put on input's value with this format, but the input can't understand this format and shows no date. If I use the browser's inspector and change the input's value to 2016-01-13 (yyyy-mm-dd format) my date is displayed correctly, and with local format (dd/MM/yyyy):

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field StartDate must be a date." data-val-required="Start Date is required" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" type="date" value="2016-01-13" />
```

[image: Input with datetime!]

I'd like to let users to see and edit with local format. How can I achieve this? I saw some suggestions about creating custom templates, but wonder if there is a simpler way of achieving this.

When I post data to actions, they are bind correctly and stored correctly. My problem starts when I try to get that value and show inside an editor so use can edit it.

Comment: Are you generating the browsers HTML5 datpicker or using a jquery plugin? If the former, add the following attribute to the property - `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`

Comment: God, I knew it would be simple. Yes, I'm using browsers HTML5, this solved everything. I did try this, but I was using wrong format, I was using ``"{0:yyyy-MM-DD}"`` with upper case D. Please, would you mind posting as answer? Thanks!

Comment: Marked as dupe instead, but note that IE and FireFox do not support the HTML5 date type so in those browsers it will just render a standard textbox input

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the advice, I'm gonna test other browsers and handle they. I read the another question you answered, I just didn't search properly (it's not a matter of how much time you spend searching, but **how** do you search).

Comment: [this site](https://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-44/firefox-40/ie-11/ie-Edge%2013/opera-31.html) is useful for comparing the support. As you can see `type="date"` is currently only supported in Chrome and Edge